# SQL Server add count column near existing select columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

i have a query that returns something like this.

```
ID | Company| Total_Money | no_items | count_Total_Money_For_Company
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | A      | 1000        | 1        | 2001
2  | A      | 1001        | 0        | 2001
3  | B      | 1001        | 1        | 5010
4  | B      | 1002        | 1        | 5010
5  | B      | 1003        | 1        | 5010
6  | B      | 1004        | 1        | 5010
7  | B      | 1000        | 1        | 5010
```

How can i add that column with the count for that company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT ID, 
       Company, 
       Total_Money, 
       no_items, 
       SUM(Total_Money) OVER(PARTITION BY Company) count_Total_Money_For_Company 
FROM   Company
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this(Uses SUM Aggregate Function):

```
SELECT id, 
       company, 
       total_money, 
       no_items, 
       SUM(total_money) OVER(PARTITION BY id) count_total_money_for_company 
FROM   <your_table >
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-SUM.asp) is the solution for your problem..

Use the SUM() sql function.. You can use it with a groupby